# Play Youtube videos on background in Nativescript

Tags: youtube, nativescript

I want to play a video from a Youtube URL or video ID and keep it playing when app unfocuses or screen locks.

Suggestions please.

I've tried `nativescript-videoplayer` but I can't get it to keep playing when app unfocuses.

Comment: I guess you will have to play it from a service to keep it running in background.

Comment: @Manoj I solved my problem it in a different way. With the plugin `nativescript-youtube-parser` I can convert a normal Youtube video URL to a URL that is playable by the `nativescript-audio` plugin. This audio plugin plays the audio of the youtube video on its own thread (?) without being interrupted when changing to other apps or locking the screen. Cheers!

Comment: Cool, anyway video player is not really meant for playing in background. Glad you figured it out.